# How to determine which type of relationship to use in database design

Tags: design-patterns, entity-framework-4, relationship

I'm designing a database and I'm stuck trying to figure out what sort of relationship I need.

I have an **Order** entity which is mapped 1-Many with an **OrderItem** entity. This works fine. However, I want to find a way to link each **OrderItem** with exactly one **Product** but the **Product** does not need to know about any of the **OrderItems**.

The problem I get is that when I attempt to add a **Product**, Entity Framework complains that I have not specified an **OrderItem**:

> Entities in 'ModelContainer.Products' participate in the 'OrderItemProducts' relationship. 0 related 'OrderItem' were found. 1 'OrderItem' is expected.

So, I don't think I have the correct type of relationship between **OrderItem** and **Product**.

My question: Do I even *need* a relationship here? If so, how can I link one OrderItem to a Product, but not vice-versa? If not, what other approach might I take?

Comment: Sounds like what you need is a 1-many relation in the opposite direction from how it currently is.  I don't know enough about EF to tell you how to do that, but i'd assume you just do what you're doing in the opposite direction.

Comment: So one Product will have Many OrderItems? That seems obvious now.

Comment: Yep.  And i assume there's also a way to tell EF not to even generate stuff in the Product that can navigate to OrderItems, if you don't care about that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems obvious now, but I had a 1-Many relationship between **OrderItem** and **Product** but it was in the *wrong* direction.

When using the model designer in Visual Studio, I needed to click from the **Product** entity *to* the **OrderItem** entity. Now, the direction is correct. The entity that you start from is the entity that becomes the '1' in the '1-Many' relationship.